# How to highlight the two min points on a plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats, plot, presentations

Le code:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    name=border,
    title=min point? how much less from 2nd min?,
    xlabel=$steps$,
    ylabel=$cost$]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (10, 1.07379615996e+13) 
        (20, 1.07856445335e+13)
        (30, 1.0766173662e+13)
        (40, 1.07576350033e+13)
        (50, 1.07507770146e+13)
        (60, 1.07456785887e+13)
        (70, 1.07426580974e+13)
        (80, 1.07414232715e+13)
        (90, 1.0740077238e+13)
       (100, 1.07381696222e+13)
    };
    \node [below] at (axis cs:  10, 1.07379615996e+13) {$1.07379615996e+13$};
    \node [below] at (axis cs:  100, 1.07381696222e+13) {$1.07381696222e+13$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Le caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Le output:

[image]

Can we do better? I think yes! Wouldn't it be cool to draw two horizontal lines from the two lowest points (hardcoded) and have their exact value on the y axis? Or anything else, better than my brute force bad attempt above (of using a label for these two points).

Comment: Finding the second minimum is tough if you don't have points in a table (even then it's no fun). But if you have the numbers already you can put them in `extra y ticks` and use a grid

Comment: @percusse for my case I know which points are the lowest, step 10 and 100. I thought of the grid, but it's an *overkill* IMHO, that's why I mentioned the horizontal lines, like a grid only for these two points..Ah yes it's difficult, that's why it would be cool to do something here to help the audience... ;)

Comment: You can test it via `ytick=data,grid=major`. They are too close to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `extra y ticks` like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    name=border,
    title=min point? how much less from 2nd min?,
    xlabel=$steps$,
    ylabel=$cost$,
    extra y ticks = {1.07379615996e+13,1.07381696222e+13},
    extra y tick style={grid=major, grid style={solid,black},y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,precision=10
    }},   
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (10, 1.07379615996e+13) 
        (20, 1.07856445335e+13)
        (30, 1.0766173662e+13)
        (40, 1.07576350033e+13)
        (50, 1.07507770146e+13)
        (60, 1.07456785887e+13)
        (70, 1.07426580974e+13)
        (80, 1.07414232715e+13)
        (90, 1.0740077238e+13)
       (100, 1.07381696222e+13)
    };
  \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but as others pointed out, the values are too close.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Manuel, I am accepting this, since for the future user they just might be not that close! ;)